# Android camera app that works with Sunscreenr camera connected via USB, with manual controls

Tags: android, usb, camera

I recently bought a Sunscreenr camera.  This is a little web-cam sized device that captures ultraviolet light.   It plugs into the USB port on an Android phone, and with the app provided by the company itself you can see real time video and can capture videos and still photos.  The company markets it as an effective way to determine if your sun screen is applied properly and hasn't worn off, but since it does a good job at showing ambient UV light I am trying to use it to measure how effective various materials are at blocking UV light  (shirts, window films, etc.)

While the camera itself is great, the support provided by the company is atrocious (I have received no response to multiple e-mails I have sent) and the app provided is also horrible, slapping a logo on every image (strangely, excluding the first 2 images I took) as well as not providing manual controls.  The latter makes it difficult to determine how well something is blocking UV light, because even with materials rated as blocking 100% of UV light, the camera cranks up the gain to the point where I can still see a little bit.

I am looking for a recommendation for an Android app which can do the following:

- supports USB cameras in general, and specifically, the sunscreenr camera device.
- provides manual control over the settings, such as shutter speed (most important), as well as ISO and aperture if possible.  If nothing else, an "exposure lock" would probably be sufficient.

I have found lots of apps which do one or the other, but I am still looking for one that does both - and reading the descriptions isn't very helpful because often the app doesn't do a good job at enumerating exactly what it does!